# How to fix lightning:input from overlapping with element next to it when editing?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, aura, slds, ui

Here is the reproducible version of the problem I am facing:

ExampleComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS212/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css"/>

    <div class="MyCompany">

        <form class="slds-form--inline">

            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <label  class="slds-form-element__label" 
                        for="field-one">Field One</label>
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <input  id="field-one" 
                            class="slds-input" 
                            type="number" 
                            value="1"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <lightning:input    type="number" 
                                        name="Field-two" 
                                        label="Field Two" 
                                        value="2">
                    </lightning:input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <lightning:input    type="number" 
                                        name="Field-three" 
                                        label="Field Three" 
                                        value="3">
                    </lightning:input>
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </form>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

On page load:

[image]

when user changing value in Field two:

[image]

when user changing value in Field one:

[image]

How to get Field two behavior same as Field one without changing `lightning:input` to `input`

**NOTE:** Please note that this may look like plain styling issue and candidate for stackoverflow but I strongly feel it has something to do with lightning/slds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use SLDS styling:

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="slds-grid">             
        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-3 ">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <lightning:input type="number" label="Field One" value="1" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                   <lightning:input type="number" label="Field Two" value="2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-3">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <lightning:input type="number" label="Field Three" value="3" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Output:

[image]

Styling used:

- **slds-grid**: used to have all 3 boxes on the same line. If removed, each lightning:input will be on a separate line, as shown in photo below:

[image: Inputs on different lines]

- **slds-col--padded**: used to add a space between the components(input boxes)
- **slds-size--1-of-1**: size of the input boxes
- **slds-medium-size--1-of-3**: used to display three elements on a line

You may check out [SLDS Sizing](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/sizing/) for the last two points.

Note: I have changed the first `<input>` to a `<lightning:input>`. You may play around with it.